# Duplicate a single character in a file

Tags: c

I am trying to duplicate a single character in input file. The problem is that my character is `'\'` and the C compiler reads it as escape character and gives me error. Any help is much appreciated! thanks!

```
int main () {
    char a;
    FILE* f1;
    f1=fopen("C:\\Users\\myusr\\Desktop\\test.txt", "r+");
    do {

        a=fgetc(f1);
        if (a=='\')
        fputc(f1, '\');
    } while (a!=EOF);
    fclose(f1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why have you duplicated `'\'` in the string literal for the path, but not in the character literals?

Comment: Did you try to escape this character : \\

Answer (score 3):

Escape the backslash with another backslash to tell the compiler it's a real backslash and not an escape character.

```
if (a=='\\')
    fputc('\\', f1);
```

Comment: I already tried the double \\, but I was using the wrong fputc syntax. I was using fputc(f1, '\\'); instead of fputc('\\' ,f1);